# How to loop through multiple div with same class and set a different input field value from select in jQuery

Tags: jquery

The problem is I have multiple divs with the same class, and inside those divs are an input field and 3 select fields. New divs are created at the push of a button with the same class, input and select.

I want it so that when I change each select option fields the value of the input is updated for the current div it is in.

```
<div class="date-dropdowns">
    <input type="hidden" id="acf-field_5a7cc784294a1-0-field_5a7cc66693348" name="acf[field_5a7cc784294a1][0][field_5a7cc66693348]" required="required" value="01/02/2015">
    <select class="day" name="date_[day]">
        <option value="">Day</option>
        <option value="01">1st</option>
        <option value="02">2nd</option>
        <option value="03">3rd</option>
        <option value="04">4th</option>
        <option value="05">5th</option>
    </select>
    <select class="month" name="date_[month]">
        <option value="">Month</option>
        <option value="01">January</option>
        <option value="02">February</option>
        <option value="03">March</option>

    </select>
    <select class="year" name="date_[year]">
        <option value="">Year</option>
        <option value="2018">2018</option>
        <option value="2017">2017</option>
        <option value="2016">2016</option>
        <option value="2015">2015</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I wrote the code below but only the first block works

```
$('div[data-name="date_of_birth"] input').each(function(index, elem) { 
    $(".day,.month,.year").change(function(){
        var val = $(elem).val();
        $('div[data-name="date_of_birth"] input').val(val);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the other `div`s are created on button press, your event listener is not attached - it's only attached to the `div`s that are present on the page when you attach the listener. You could use something like this to work dynamically with newly added `div`s:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function() {
  var ipt = $(this).siblings('input');
  var day = $(this).parent().find('.day').val();
  var month = $(this).parent().find('.month').val();
  var year = $(this).parent().find('.year').val();
  var dmy = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
  ipt.val(dmy);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y499tvg1/

Edit: For your application, try this perhaps:

```
jQuery('.date-dropdowns').on('change', '.day,.month,.year', function() {
    var d = jQuery(this).parent().find('.day').val();
    var m = jQuery(this).parent().find('.month').val();
    var y = jQuery(this).parent().find('.year').val();
    var dmy = d + '/' + m + '/' + y;
    jQuery(this).parent().find('input[type=hidden]').val(dmy);
});
```

Comment: Please view how my form is setup https://autravelservice.com/verification/

Comment: Your code works, could i replace document with a class like ( .dates ) or attribute like ( div[data-name="date_of_birth"] )?

Comment: You can use any selector you want, so long as the element you are attaching the listener to is 1. already on the page when the event is attached and 2. contains the select elements as nested elements (children or grandchildren), so the event can "bubble up" the DOM to the selected element.

Comment: Edited for you!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to loop over each of the `.date-dropdowns`, which can be done with **[`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)**. Then you would need to find the relevant `input` with **[`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)**. Assign some placeholders to handle `day`, `month` and `year`, and update these when each of the respective fields are changed.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
$('.date-dropdowns').each(function(key, value) {
  // Set up variables
  const input = $(this).find('input')[0];
  let day = 'unknown';
  let month = 'unknown';
  let year = 'unknown';
  
  // Update when a selection is changed
  $(this).find('select').on('change', function() {
    
    // Check which value is updating
    if ($(this).hasClass('day')) {
      day = $(this).val();
    }
    if ($(this).hasClass('month')) {
      month = $(this).val();
    }
    if ($(this).hasClass('year')) {
      year = $(this).val();
    }

    // Update the input and log out its value
    input.value = day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
    console.log(input.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="date-dropdowns">
  <input type="hidden" id="acf-field_5a7cc784294a1-0-field_5a7cc66693348" name="acf[field_5a7cc784294a1][0][field_5a7cc66693348]" required="required" value="01/02/2015">
  <select class="day" name="date_[day]">
    <option value="">Day</option>
    <option value="01">1st</option>
    <option value="02">2nd</option>
    <option value="03">3rd</option>
    <option value="04">4th</option>
    <option value="05">5th</option>
  </select>
  <select class="month" name="date_[month]">
    <option value="">Month</option>
    <option value="01">January</option>
    <option value="02">February</option>
    <option value="03">March</option>
  </select>
  <select class="year" name="date_[year]">
    <option value="">Year</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: What if <div class="date-dropdowns"></div> is appended after the page is loaded, how would i select it?

Comment: `.each()` works with dynamically-created elements :)

Comment: I add your code to my jquery script but it doesn't work please view how it is setup at the link below https://autravelservice.com/verification/